# Validation pipe works with one value type but not several types at the same time

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I created 3 DTOs which extends from another parent DTO and then in the controller I use class-validator library to validate the data the user pass to the controller.

**parent.dto.ts**

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString, IsDateString, IsMongoId } from 'class-validator';

export class Parent {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  platform: string;
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  admins: string[];
  @IsDateString()
  purchaseDate: Date;
  @IsDateString()
  validFrom: Date;
  @IsDateString()
  validTo: Date;
}
```

**a.dto.ts**

```
import { IsMongoId, IsNotEmpty, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { Parent } from './parent.dto';

class A_options {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  dataA: string;
}

export class A extends Parent {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  testA: string;
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => A_options)
  data: A_options;
}
```

**b.dto.ts**

```
import { IsMongoId, IsNotEmpty, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { Parent } from './parent.dto';

class B_options {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  dataB: string;
}

export class B extends Parent {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  testB: string;
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => B_options)
  data: B_options;
}
```

**c.dto.ts**

```
import { IsMongoId, IsNotEmpty, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { Parent } from './parent.dto';

class C_options {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  dataC: string;
}

export class C extends Parent {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  testC: string;
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => C_options)
  data: C_options;
}
```

And in the controller I'm using `ValidationPipe` setting `body: A`

**controller.ts**

```
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  @Post()
  async createItem(@Res() res, @Body() body: A) {
    const result = await this.createTest.createObject(body);
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
      message: 'Item has been created successfully',
      newLicense,
    });
  }
}
```

This works also with `body: B` and `body: C`

**But it doesn't work when I do `body: A | B | C`**

**How can I make it work so the code will be like this?**

```
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  @Post()
  async createItem(@Res() res, @Body() body: A | B | C) {
    const result = await this.createTest.createObject(body);
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
      message: 'Item has been created successfully',
      newLicense,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would simply recommend to implement a `IParent` interface and extend it in your `Parent` class.

Then you can use the `IParent` in your controller, as such:

#### controller.ts

```js
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
@Post()
async createItem(@Res() res, @Body() body: IParent) {
  const result = await this.createTest.createObject(body);
  return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
    message: 'Item has been created successfully',
    newLicense,
  });
}
```

#### parent.interface.ts

```js
export interface IParent {
  platform: string;
  admins: string[];
  purchaseDate: Date;
  validFrom: Date;
  validTo: Date;
}
```

#### parent.class.ts

```js
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString, IsDateString, IsMongoId } from 'class-validator';

export class Parent implements IParent {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  platform: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  admins: string[];

  @IsDateString()
  purchaseDate: Date;

  @IsDateString()
  validFrom: Date;

  @IsDateString()
  validTo: Date;
}
```

Let me know if it helps; if so validate answer, otherwise please provide a link to a repository with minimal reproduction so we can help further.